# Why Facebook Graph does not allow me to delete a post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I have a page access token with the following details:

- Expires   Never
- Valid True
- Origin    Web
- Scopes    create_note, export_stream, manage_pages, photo_upload, publish_actions, publish_stream, read_mailbox, read_stream, share_item, status_update, user_friends, video_upload

Still, when i try to delete a post from the page i got that access token I get this response:

```
{"error": {
  "message": "(#200) User does not have sufficient administrative permission for this action on this page",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 200 
  }
}
```

The access token for the page was obtained using this call `GET /{user-id}/accounts`. i have to mention that the user access token with the same permissions doesn't work either.

What am I missing?

Thanks!
Petre Tudor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response you're getting from facebook itself says that the user with the access to the page you're trying to `DELETE` the post of, doesn't have the right permissions to do so.

This is because your account/user doesn't hold a role which gives rights to delete the posts from the page. The account must be holding one of these roles - `Moderator`, `Advertiser`, `Insights Analyst`. Only the `Manager` and the `Content Creator` has rights to delete posts from the pages.

Hence, you should either get one of those roles (The admin can change the role for you) or authenticate the app from a Manager/Content Creator's account.

For more details, you can check out their official help section - [What are the different kinds of Page admins and what can they do?](http://www.facebook.com/help/www/289207354498410)

Hope that helps!